# Does jsoup support xpath?

Tags: xpath, jsoup

There's some work in progress related to adding xpath support to jsoup https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/80.

- Is it working?
- How can I use it?

Comment: There is a boatload of information on this topic out there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816878/jsoup-css-selector-code-xpath-code-included https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335820/convert-xpath-to-jsoup-query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791596/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-an-html-element https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jsoup/lj4_-EJwH1Q

Answer (score 13):

**JSoup** doesn't support *XPath* yet, but you may try [**XSoup**](https://github.com/code4craft/xsoup) - *"Jsoup with XPath"*.

Here's an example quoted from the projects Github site ([link](https://github.com/code4craft/xsoup)):

```
@Test
public void testSelect() {

    String html = "<html><div><a href='https://github.com'>github.com</a></div>" +
            "<table><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr></table></html>";

    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

    String result = Xsoup.compile("//a/@href").evaluate(document).get();
    Assert.assertEquals("https://github.com", result);

    List<String> list = Xsoup.compile("//tr/td/text()").evaluate(document).list();
    Assert.assertEquals("a", list.get(0));
    Assert.assertEquals("b", list.get(1));
}
```

There you'll also find a list of features and expressions of XPath that are supported by XSoup.

Comment: (This was correct when written; but jsoup now does support XPath, see answer below.)

Answer (score 2):

Not yet,but the project [JsoupXpath](https://github.com/zhegexiaohuozi/JsoupXpath) has make it.For example,

```
String html = "<html><body><script>console.log('aaaaa')</script><div class='test'>some body</div><div class='xiao'>Two</div></body></html>";
JXDocument underTest = JXDocument.create(html);
String xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'xiao')]/text()";
JXNode node = underTest.selNOne(xpath);
Assert.assertEquals("Two",node.asString());
```

By the way,it supports the complete W3C XPATH 1.0 standard syntax.Such as

```
//ul[@class='subject-list']/li[./div/div/span[@class='pl']/num()>(1000+90*(2*50))][last()][1]/div/h2/allText()
//ul[@class='subject-list']/li[not(contains(self::li/div/div/span[@class='pl']//text(),'14582'))]/div/h2//text()
```

Answer (score 0):

[HtmlUnit](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/) supports XPath. I've used this for certain projects and it works reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, jsoup now natively supports XPath.** I added Xpath support to jsoup in version [1.14.3](https://jsoup.org/news/release-1.14.3), released in 2021.

For example:

```java
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jsoup.org/").get();
  
  Elements elements = doc.selectXpath("//div[@class='col1']/p");
      // Each P element in div.col1
  
  List<TextNode> textNodes = doc.selectXpath("//a/text()", TextNode.class);
      // Each TextNode in every A element
```

See the [XPath cookbook guide](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/xpath-syntax) for more information.