# How to get line from table with Jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

I have table without any class or id (there are more tables on the page) with this structure:

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
...  
     <tr>
          <td class="cell_c">...</td>
          <td class="cell_c">...</td>
          <td class="cell_c">...</td>
          <td class="cell">SOME_ID</td>
          <td class="cell_c">...</td>
     </tr>
...
</table>
```

I want to get only one row, which contains `<td class="cell">SOME_ID</td>` and SOME_ID is an argument.

---

UPD.
Currently i am doing iy in this way:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bank.gov.ua/control/uk/curmetal/detail/currency?period=daily").get();

      Elements rows = doc.select("table tr");
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*(USD|EUR|RUB).*$");

      for (Element trow : rows) {
          Matcher m = p.matcher(trow.text());   
          if(m.find()){                   
               System.out.println(m.group());              
          }
      }
```

But why i need Jsoup if most of work is done by regexp ? To download HTML ?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I can only select all <tr> and then in loop check if they contain SOME_ID. But the problem is that page have multiple tables with different structures.

Comment: can you use xpath? but look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816878/jsoup-css-selector-code-xpath-code-included

Comment: Is the content HTML static, meaning always the same structure?

Comment: @Daniel B, Yes, it always same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a generic HTML structure that always is the same, and you want a specific element which has no unique ID or identifier attribute that you can use, you can use the css selector syntax in Jsoup to specify where in the DOM-tree the element you are after is located.

Consider this HTML source:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%"> 
   <tbody>
    <tr> 
     <td class="cell">I don't want this one...</td> 
     <td class="cell">Neither do I want this one...</td> 
     <td class="cell">Still not the right one..</td> 
     <td class="cell">BINGO!</td> 
     <td class="cell">Nothing further...</td> 
    </tr> ... 
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

We want to select and parse the text from the fourth `<td>` element.
We specify that we want to select the `<td>` element that has the index 3 in the DOM-tree, by using `td:eq(3)`. In the same way, we can select all `<td>` elements before index 3 by using `td:lt(3)`. As you've probably figured out, this is `equal` and `less than`.

Without using `first()` you will get an `Elements` object, but we only want the first one so we specify that. We could use `get(0)` instead too.

So, the following code

```
Element e = doc.select("td:eq(3)").first();
System.out.println("Did I find it? " + e.text());
```

will output

```
Did I find it? BINGO!
```

Some good reading in the [Jsoup cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)!