# Convert xPath to JSoup query

Tags: xpath, jsoup

Does anyone know of an xPath to JSoup convertor?  I get the following xPath from Chrome:

```
 //*[@id="docs"]/div[1]/h4/a
```

and would like to change it into a Jsoup query.  The path contains an href I'm trying to reference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is very easy to convert manually.

Something like this (not tested)

```
document.select("#docs > div:eq(1) > h4 > a").attr("href");
```

Documentation:

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

---

### Related question from comment

> Trying to get the href for the first result here:
>   cbssports.com/info/search#q=fantasy%20tom%20brady

**Code**

```
Elements select = Jsoup.connect("http://solr.cbssports.com/solr/select/?q=fantasy%20tom%20brady")
        .get()
        .select("response > result > doc > str[name=url]");

for (Element element : select) {
    System.out.println(element.html());
}
```

**Result**

```
http://fantasynews.cbssports.com/fantasyfootball/players/playerpage/187741/tom-brady
http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/players/playerpage/187741/tom-brady
http://fantasynews.cbssports.com/fantasycollegefootball/players/playerpage/1825265/brady-lisoski
http://fantasynews.cbssports.com/fantasycollegefootball/players/playerpage/1766777/blake-brady
http://fantasynews.cbssports.com/fantasycollegefootball/players/playerpage/1851211/brady-foltz
http://fantasynews.cbssports.com/fantasycollegefootball/players/playerpage/1860955/brady-earnhardt
http://fantasynews.cbssports.com/fantasycollegefootball/players/playerpage/1673397/brady-amack
```

Screenshot from Developer Console - grabbing urls

[image]

Comment: Not working, but maybe not the fault of your answer.  Trying to get the href for the first result here: http://www.cbssports.com/info/search#q=fantasy%20tom%20brady

Comment: You mean this? http://solr.cbssports.com/solr/select/?q=fantasy%20tom%20brady This page is loaded incrementally via AJAX, so you need to access this data directly like AJAX in Jsoup.

Comment: Thanks a million!  Are there any good resources on loading AJAX resources via Jsoup?

Comment: I dont know, probably many, Im using Google Chrome https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Can you please explain how you got the url you used from the one in my comment?  I am working on parsing another page from this site and having trouble with it as well.

Comment: Run page in Chrome, turn on Developer Tools, look at request to server. All network traffic is here.

Comment: screen from console added to answer

Comment: Ok, I really hate to continue to ask for help, but I am so lost.  Are the headers and articles on this page also loaded via script: http://fantasynews.cbssports.com/fantasyfootball/players/updates/187741

Comment: Ask new question please :)

Answer (score 18):

I am using **Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.73 m (64-bit)** and I can now directly copy the Selector path which is compatible with `JSoup`

[image: Chrome with Selector option]

Copied Selector of the element in the screenshot `span.com` is 
`#question > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.postcell > div > div.post-text > pre > code > span.com`

Comment: I did selector path on a table, all it returned was the `#id` tag on the element. Can you please check ?

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same using Firefox?

Comment: @AhmedRana I have not tried it on Firefox, but this option should be there in Dev Tools of Firefox.

Comment: does not really work with a syntax like \@

Answer (score 4):

You don't necessarily need to convert Xpath to JSoup specific selectors.

Instead you can use XSoup which is based on JSoup and supports Xpath.

https://github.com/code4craft/xsoup

Here is an example using XSoup from the docs.

```
@Test
public void testSelect() {

    String html = "<html><div><a href='https://github.com'>github.com</a></div>" +
            "<table><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr></table></html>";

    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

    String result = Xsoup.compile("//a/@href").evaluate(document).get();
    Assert.assertEquals("https://github.com", result);

    List<String> list = Xsoup.compile("//tr/td/text()").evaluate(document).list();
    Assert.assertEquals("a", list.get(0));
    Assert.assertEquals("b", list.get(1));
}
```

Comment: Great this improved the performance to a certain extent.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the following XPath and Jsoup, it works.

example 1:

[XPath]

```html
//*[@id="docs"]/div[1]/h4/a
```

[JSoup]

```js
document.select("#docs > div > h4 > a").attr("href");
```

---

example 2:

[XPath]

```html
//*[@id="action-bar-container"]/div/div[2]/a[2]
```

[JSoup]

```js
document.select("#action-bar-container > div > div:eq(1) > a:eq(1)").attr("href");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working standalone snippet using Xsoup with Jsoup:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import us.codecraft.xsoup.Xsoup;

public class TestXsoup {
    public static void main(String[] args){

            String html = "<html><div><a href='https://github.com'>github.com</a></div>" +
                    "<table><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr></table></html>";

            Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

            List<String> filasFiltradas = Xsoup.compile("//tr/td/text()").evaluate(document).list();
            System.out.println(filasFiltradas);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
[a, b]
```

Libraries included:

xsoup-0.3.1.jar
jsoup-1.103.jar

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is pretty old, I just want to mention that latest Jsoup release has some Beta features like the one requested in this question.

Release **1.14.3** added a native XPath selector. See it for yourselves: https://jsoup.org/news/release-1.14.3

Now you can use Jsoup native methods:

```java
    File downloadedPage = new File("/path/to/your/page.html");
    String xPathSelector = "//*[@id="docs"]/div[1]/h4/a";
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(downloadedPage, "UTF-8");
    Elements elements = document.selectXpath(xPathSelector);
```

You can iterate over the `elements` returned!

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want.

```
Document doc = JSoup.parse(googleURL);
doc.select("cite") //to get all the cite elements in the page

doc.select("li > cite") //to get all the <cites>'s that only exist under the <li>'s

doc.select("li.g cite") //to only get the <cite> tags under <li class=g> tags


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String html = getHTML();
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements elems = doc.select("li.g > cite");
    for(Element elem: elems){
        System.out.println(elem.toString());
    }
}
```