# How to extract relative Xpaths of a WebPage from a URL

Tags: dom, xpath, jsoup, html-parsing, sample

I am working on a program to list out the elements inside a webpage and their corresponding relative xpaths.
Using Java and JSoup, I want to extract relative Xpaths created dynamically for all the elements inside any given webPage. A complete and small working utility will definitely help me here.

**I want something like:**

`//*[@id="menu-item-13686"]/a`

**Sample output:**

`Element Or Node or component Name: xxxx AND Xpath = //*[@id="menu-item-13686"]/a`

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335820/convert-xpath-to-jsoup-query

Comment: Hello @JeroenHeier, as suggested I have updated my question, but not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: Hello @Luk, Thank you, I have see the link provided, however, I am looking for something the other way. I am actually trying to build a map of list Xpaths for all the existing elements or components dynamically from the webPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can start with this.

> **Issue got fixed in version jOOX - 1.6.1**  *Compiled with Java 10*
>
> Refer https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOX/issues/158

The below code snippet selects all the elements and for each element prints out node name, tag name and CSS selector and Xpath that will uniquely select this element.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.joox.selector.CSS2XPath;

public class TestParser {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://theuserisdrunk.com/").get();
        Elements elements = doc.select("*");
        for (Element element : elements) {
            String path = CSS2XPath.css2xpath(element.cssSelector(), true);
            System.out.println("Node name : " + element.nodeName());
            System.out.println("      Tag : " + element.tagName());
            System.out.println("      CSS : " + element.cssSelector());
            System.out.println("    XPath : " + path + "\n");

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Sample Output:

```
 Node name : div
      Tag : div
      CSS : #mc-embedded-subscribe-form > div.clear:nth-child(4)
    XPath : //*[@id='mc-embedded-subscribe-form']/div[@class='clear' or starts-with(@class, 'clear ') or ' clear' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' clear') + 1) or contains(@class, ' clear ')][count(preceding-sibling::*) = 4 - 1]

Node name : input
      Tag : input
      CSS : #mc-embedded-subscribe
    XPath : //*[@id='mc-embedded-subscribe']

Node name : p
      Tag : p
      CSS : #mc_embed_signup > p.intern:nth-child(2)
    XPath : //*[@id='mc_embed_signup']/p[@class='intern' or starts-with(@class, 'intern ') or ' intern' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' intern') + 1) or contains(@class, ' intern ')][count(preceding-sibling::*) = 2 - 1]

Node name : a
      Tag : a
      CSS : #mc_embed_signup > p.intern:nth-child(2) > a
    XPath : //*[@id='mc_embed_signup']/p[@class='intern' or starts-with(@class, 'intern ') or ' intern' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' intern') + 1) or contains(@class, ' intern ')][count(preceding-sibling::*) = 2 - 1]/a

Node name : p
      Tag : p
      CSS : #mc_embed_signup > p.intern:nth-child(3)
    XPath : //*[@id='mc_embed_signup']/p[@class='intern' or starts-with(@class, 'intern ') or ' intern' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' intern') + 1) or contains(@class, ' intern ')][count(preceding-sibling::*) = 3 - 1]

Node name : i
      Tag : i
      CSS : #mc_embed_signup > p.intern:nth-child(3) > i
    XPath : //*[@id='mc_embed_signup']/p[@class='intern' or starts-with(@class, 'intern ') or ' intern' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' intern') + 1) or contains(@class, ' intern ')][count(preceding-sibling::*) = 3 - 1]/i

Node name : p
      Tag : p
      CSS : #mc_embed_signup > p.intern:nth-child(4)
    XPath : //*[@id='mc_embed_signup']/p[@class='intern' or starts-with(@class, 'intern ') or ' intern' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' intern') + 1) or contains(@class, ' intern ')][count(preceding-sibling::*) = 4 - 1]

Node name : a
      Tag : a
      CSS : #mc_embed_signup > p.intern:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)
    XPath : //*[@id='mc_embed_signup']/p[@class='intern' or starts-with(@class, 'intern ') or ' intern' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' intern') + 1) or contains(@class, ' intern ')][count(preceding-sibling::*) = 4 - 1]/a[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 1 - 1]

Node name : a
      Tag : a
      CSS : #mc_embed_signup > p.intern:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(2)
    XPath : //*[@id='mc_embed_signup']/p[@class='intern' or starts-with(@class, 'intern ') or ' intern' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' intern') + 1) or contains(@class, ' intern ')][count(preceding-sibling::*) = 4 - 1]/a[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 2 - 1]

Node name : i
      Tag : i
      CSS : #mc_embed_signup > p.intern:nth-child(4) > i
    XPath : //*[@id='mc_embed_signup']/p[@class='intern' or starts-with(@class, 'intern ') or ' intern' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' intern') + 1) or contains(@class, ' intern ')][count(preceding-sibling::*) = 4 - 1]/i

Node name : a
      Tag : a
      CSS : #mc_embed_signup > p.intern:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(4)
    XPath : //*[@id='mc_embed_signup']/p[@class='intern' or starts-with(@class, 'intern ') or ' intern' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' intern') + 1) or contains(@class, ' intern ')][count(preceding-sibling::*) = 4 - 1]/a[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 4 - 1]

Node name : a
      Tag : a
      CSS : #mc_embed_signup > p.intern:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(5)
    XPath : //*[@id='mc_embed_signup']/p[@class='intern' or starts-with(@class, 'intern ') or ' intern' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' intern') + 1) or contains(@class, ' intern ')][count(preceding-sibling::*) = 4 - 1]/a[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 5 - 1]

Node name : script
      Tag : script
      CSS : html > body > script:nth-child(3)
    XPath : //html/body/script[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 3 - 1]

Node name : script
      Tag : script
      CSS : html > body > script:nth-child(4)
    XPath : //html/body/script[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 4 - 1]
```

Comment: Thank you Abilash, I will try this out. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hello Abhilash, Thanks for your help. I have tried the code and it worked but actually partially. The sample out put that I got is "html > body > div.wrap > div.text > p:nth-child(4) > a.website:nth-child(1)", but I was looking for something like "/html/body/div[2]/div/p[2]/a[1]" (taken from chrome inspect) or to be precise, I want relative paths of every component or link inside a HTML page. Could you please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: @NewBieDev, updated the answer to get xpath using jooq

Comment: Sweet! Thank you @Abhilash, let me try this. Thank you so much for your quick response. Thanks again!

Comment: @NewBieDev, did you get what you want?

Comment: Hello Abhilash, I tried the sample it actually worked, however, I found something which I am not able to make out. Ex: There is this XPath I got for one of my URL- " .//html/body/script[position() = 62]" and the CSS : "html > body > script:nth-child(62)". Now, what I observed is that if you search the CSS in Inspect mode in Chrome, I am able to find the element, but not through the XPath. Surprisingly, when I took the Xpath of the same searched element from Chrome, I got this "/html/body/script[60]".There is a difference but I am not able to make out why. Its an Angular application.Kindly help

Comment: if this solved your problem, accept the answer and update your post or create new question.

Comment: please check the updated answer. use the 1.6.1 version of jOOX.

Comment: Thank you Abhilash. However, we are not using Java 10 in our project yet. Not sure how to mitigate this issue which I understood that there is difficulty in gathering Xpaths of all the elements where the website is Javascript rendered.

Comment: you can download jOOX source code, complie it using whatever java version you want and use it in your project. That's how I did to test my code. I am using Java 8.

Comment: Sure will do as suggested

Comment: Hi @Abilash, I have tried and it almost worked perfectly. However, when I am trying to access a JS rendered website (react, angular) internal to our company, the program is missing out many elements which were actually visible in Chrome Inspect. Is there any way to mitigate this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSoup is an HTML parser, not some kind of embedded browser engine. This means that it's completely unaware of any content that is added to the DOM by Javascript after the initial page load. You need to use a framework like Selenium.

Comment: I agree with you @Abhilash.I just tried saving the web page as a HTML file and executed. Now, I observed that I see the items which were JS rendered and their Xpaths. But, wanted to check if there is a way to remove all the unnecessary stuff inside the Xpath. I mean, I got a long Xpath String for one specific element/attribute which has `"or starts-with ()", "or ' ng-invalid-required' = substring(@class, string-length(@class) - string-length(' ng-invalid-required') + 1) or contains(@class,"`. This Xpath is or 5 lines in output.Could I get a much simpler and crisp Xpath.Can you help me here plz